# Typescript Generic Methods

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a method where i want to pass in a generic object array. I want to also pass in the objects properties to look for.

As the property names can changed i want to switch description and value with what i ever i pass in.

How do i do this, how do i pass in the property and pull out its value from the object array?

By executing the following i know if the properties exist:

```
console.log(obj[key].hasOwnProperty(strDisplay))
console.log(obj[key].hasOwnProperty(strValue))


public Test<T>(obj: T[], strDisplay: string, strValue: string) {

    const pickList: PickListOption[] = [];

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

      const option: IPickListOption = {
        display:obj[key].description  ,
        value: obj[key].value
      };

      pickList.push(option);

    })

    return pickList;
  }
```

I want to be able to return a new list 'pickList' with key values pairs of display and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `Object.keys` for an array seems a bit off. For transforming an array to another array `map` is a much better choice.

With regard to picking the two keys you will need `strDisplay` and `strValue` to be value keyof `T` in order to use indexing into the object:

```
interface PickListOption { value: unknown, display: unknown }
function Test<T>(arr: T[], strDisplay: keyof T, strValue: keyof T) {

  return arr.map((o): PickListOption => ({
    display: o[strDisplay],
    value: o[strValue]
  }))
}
```

You could also restrict the keys to only a specific type of value using a special mapped and conditional type:

```
type KeysOfValueType<T, TValue> = {
  [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends TValue ? P: never
}[keyof T]

interface PickListOption { value: number, display: string }
function Test<T>(arr: T[], strDisplay: KeysOfValueType<T, string>, strValue: KeysOfValueType<T, number>) {

  return arr.map((o): PickListOption => ({
    display: o[strDisplay] as unknown as string,
    value: o[strValue] as unknown as number
  }));
}
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the quick reply. The reason behind going for a generic method was that I have to remap about 20 arrays. I was just looking to cut down on the replication of the same code.

Your first method works great. 

Many thanks